# Как правильно написать предложение?С предлогом или без?

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно написать?С каким предлогом или без него?Методика спортивного плавания "у" детей старшего школьного возраста или "для детей"?А может быть вообще без предлога?Как,например,в другом случае-"методика музыкального воспитания детей..."

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

МЕТОДИКА,  чего. 1. Совокупность методов, приёмов практического выполнения чего-л. М. научного исследования.  2. Раздел педагогики, рассматривающий методы преподавания учебных предметов, воспитания кого-л. М. преподавания истории.

Здесь явно речь идет о методике преподавания предмета "спортивное плавание".

Поэтому: методика (чего?) обучения, обучения (чему?) спортивному плаванию, обучения (кого?) детей старшего школьного возраста.

Получается: **Методика обучения спортивному плаванию детей старшего школьного возраста** (уже предложенный здесь вариант).

Answer (score 1):

Если предположить, что это методика плавания для самообучения:

> Методика спортивного плавания [, предназначенная] **для** детей...
>
> (более формально: Методика спортивного плавания. Для детей ... возраста)

Беспредложный же вариант "Методика плавания детей..." оставляет странное впечатление, будто по ней "детей плавают" - поскольку типичное применение выражения со  словом "методика" такое: "методика произведения действия над чем-то".

Если же это *не* самоучитель, а методический материал, то предпочтителен вариант:

> Методика **обучения** спортивному плаванию детей...